# magento 1.9: How to load customers by mobile number

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, model

I want to **load customer** and get his data from **telephone number**
we have `load()` methods, to load customer by id as well as we have `loadByEmail()` to load customer by Email but i want to load customer by providing his telephone number and get his data.

Comment: Thanks 
But i have gone through that answer earlier but that dint seemed to helped me
Thus i asked for it :)

Comment: Then you should mention it in the question: what did you try? what happened? As it stands, the exact question has been asked before and you would not get a different answer.

Comment: Yes but i am that much not familier about it
Sorry for that and Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `load` function the second parameter is the field to load, by default `entity_id`

Your need is `$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('123456', 'phone_number_attribute_code');`

```
/**
 * Load object data
 *
 * @param   integer $id
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($id, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can search by below code, you can set your attribute value instead of telephone:

```
$telephone = '32423423';

$result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('telephone', $telephone) //replace your attribute of mobile
    ->load();

if (is_object($result)) {
    //set your code...
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in \Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php:816 Stack trace: #0 Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(1377): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->isAttributeStatic('telephone') #1 \app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(321): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('telephone', '123456', 'inner') #2 \cust.php(30): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('telephone', '7838183888') #3 {main} thrown in Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: I have tried your solution but got the above error :(
can you please help me out what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

At magento telephone is Customer address attribute.

If you want to ***get Customer details from telephone*** then you need to **check Customer Id** from `Mage::getModel('customer/address')` model.

```
    $CustomAddress=Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('telephone',$YourValue)->getFirstItem();

    $customerId= $CustomAddress->getCustomerId($CustomAddress);
```

Then using Customer id,**You can get Custome data by load Customer model**

```
$customer = Mage::getModel(‘customer/customer’)->load($customerId);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but got the following error 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Collection::getFirstIem() in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\cust.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\cust.php on line 25

can you please help me out if i am doing something wrong??

Comment: `getFirstIem` should be `getFirstItem`

Comment: still i am not able to get all the data 
i am just getting the customer created date time...
well i will have a look at it again :)
Thanks for the help :D

Comment: I will check and get back to ypu